# product of double.PositiveInfinity and i

Tags: c#, complex-numbers

I ran into the following very strange product in C#. The test below passes.

```
public void InfinityTimesITest() {
  Complex infinity = new Complex(double.PositiveInfinity, 0);
  Complex i = new Complex(0, 1);
  Complex product = infinity * i;
  double real = product.Real;
  double imaginary = product.Imaginary;
  Assert.IsNaN(real);
  Assert.IsTrue(Double.IsPositiveInfinity(imaginary));
}
```

It also passes if you reverse the order of terms in the product. But thinking about this mathematically, what C# appears to be saying is:

```
 infinity * i = (real NaN) + infinity * i.
```

That seems like a strange choice. There must be some thinking behind it. I'm hoping someone here can provide some insight into what is going on.

Comment: The product of infinity and zero is mathematically undefined, which C# represents with NaN. The conceptual problem here is that there is no proper complex number with a positive infinity real part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it just expands complex multiplication like this:

```
(inf + 0i) * (0 + i) = inf * 0 + inf * i + 0i * 0 + 0i * i = inf * 0 + inf * i
```

First term is product of infinity and zero - so Nan. Second term is imaginary infinity.

EDIT: if look at sources, complex multiplication operator looks like this:

```
public static Complex operator *(Complex left, Complex right)
{
  return new Complex(left.m_real * right.m_real - left.m_imaginary * right.m_imaginary, left.m_imaginary * right.m_real + left.m_real * right.m_imaginary);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not a multiplication by an imaginary number i, it's multiplication by a complex number 0+i. There is a conceptual difference: for the latter, the real part could be truly zero or just too small to represent. The multiplication basically makes the real part of the result zero times infinity, which is supposed to be NaN.

Comment: For the double multiplication it is a correct behavior (inf * 0 = NaN) because it is out of context, but in the context of Complex multiplications it is a bug and Complex multiply opeartor should have handled it.

Comment: @Some1Pr0 Again, *why* is it wrong? How do you distinguish an imaginary number from a complex number with a too-small-to-represent real part?

Comment: If it is too small to represent and you care about the lost too small part than you should'nt use this class. when the double is set to 0 the small part is already lost and it should be treated as 0

Comment: @Some1Pr0 That exact same argument could be made to plain `double`, but you do think it makes sense for zero times infinity to return NaN there.

Comment: In double it isn't but the Complex is not 0, it is i, and `Inf × i` is (inf i) not NaN. the second number is not 0 it is i and if the real part is 0 it should be ignored and not be multiplied at all.

Comment: @Some1Pr0 That's what I highlighted in my answer. i is an imaginary number. Multiplication of a real number and an imaginary number should produce an imaginary number. For multiplication of infinity by i, I would agree that you get an imaginary infinity. But .NET doesn't support imaginary numbers. It just supports complex numbers, which should usually be good enough. In complex numbers, you cannot actually represent i directly, you can only get 0+i. IIRC, C has `_Imaginary` separately from `_Complex`, and there multiplication depends on which type you use.

Answer (score 0):

Reflecting `Complex *operator` you can see it is defind by:

```
[DynamicallyInvokable]
public static Complex operator *(Complex left, Complex right)
{
    return new Complex(left.m_real * right.m_real - left.imaginary * right.m_imaginary, left.imaginary * right.m_real + left.m_real * right.m_real);
}
```

Which is good for most case, only one problem:

when `left.m_real` is `double.PositiveInfinity` and `right.m_real` is 0, The first operation `left.m_real * right.m_real` is `Double.NaN` (that is also why the muliplication order doesn't matter).
It seems like an unwanted behavior since the logicly the calculation done in the `operator` is correct for every finite number but `0 * infinite` is defined incorrectly **for that case**.

I guess it's a bug in the `operator` because **mathematically it is wrong**.

Comment: I already posted an answer explaining why having a real part of `NaN` is correct. If you disagree with it, it would be more constructive to say *why* you feel having `NaN` is wrong, rather than just claiming it must be a bug.

Comment: It's a bug in the Complex multiply operator not in double's operator, since mathematically it is wrong for the multiplication of Complexes.

Comment: There is no mathematically valid result for this operation, because infinity isn't a real. In other words, the complex plane does not extend in the reals axis to infinity.